# Tips for migrating a very large ASP.NET MVC 5.2 SaaS application to ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for some advice on how to go about a very large and complex migration of a SaaS ASP.NET MVC 5.2 web application.  Some general stats:

~630 Controllers
~1020 aspx files
~840 ascx files
~1000 Entity classes for **Linq2SQL** (our data model has ~1K tables)

We'd like to target migrating to ASP.NET MVC Core on .NET 6, and possibly to Entity Framework Core.

To make things a little more complicated, our application is a SaaS where we release a new version every 2 or 3 months.  I don't know, but I feel like this is going to be impossible to do in a single release given the scale.  I feel like this is going to be a project that spans 3 or more releases, so we need to figure out how to do this incrementally.

Essentially, my thought is that we will deploy two applications moving forward, and migrate pages incrementally from the old application to the new one.  This should all be seamless to the end user.  They should not be able to tell which pages are being served from the old MVC, and which ones are being served from the new one.  We use nginx for our load balancer.  I'm hoping this is something nginx can help us with.

This is all happening while new features are still expected to be added in the upcoming releases.

We have a team of about 25 developers.  My guess is most of them are still going to be building new features, and maybe 3-5 of them will be working on this migration..

So, a couple of questions:

1. Does this seem like a reasonable approach to this migration?
2. Has anybody out there gone through a migration like this?  Any advice?  What am I glossing over?

Comment: you mention MVC and then "aspx", "ascx" which belong to WebForms. am I missing something, or MVC can handle them?

Comment: Yes.  Older versions of ASP.NET MVC used aspx/ascx pages before they added the razor pages.

Comment: My advice is whatever you do with the new businesslayer code then also try to get CI so you can deploy it whenever. But maybe this question is better asked on softwareengineering forum

Comment: Start by moving as much code as possible to a .net standard library, and then start the UI part from scratch.

Comment: I guess my question was more around the idea of running two sites concurrently--one with the old ASP.NET MVC code, and the other with the new ASP.NET MVC Core code, while making the whole thing look like a single application to the end user.  I'm not entirely sure how best to pull this off.

Comment: I think you can refer to azure [app service – slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) to think about your migration.  In my opinion, you wanna a  seamless experience for end users, absolutely you need multiple endpoints(slots) to make the new code(in asp.net core) run along with the old version.  If the new version(in asp.net core) has different ui with the old one, or have some new features which will affect user operation or backend api, I think it’s better to  sync the old version.